# Linq join - check for records in join table

Tags: c#, linq

My link query

```
 var q = from l in db.Locations

         select new LocationWrap {
                        Location = l
```

returns one row per location

until I add:

```
 var q = from l in db.Locations

         join lcl in db.Location_Catering_Links on l.ID equals lcl.LID into catering from lcl in catering.DefaultIfEmpty()    

         select new LocationWrap {
                        Location = l,
                        hasCatering = (lcl != null)
```

It then returns many location records (as many as there are). I believe it might be doing a left outer join, when all I need is a boolean of whether there is any catering records.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Location_Catering_Links` navigation property in your location entity you can do the following.

```
var q = from l in db.Locations
        select new LocationWrap
               {
                   Location = l,
                   hasCatering = l.Location_Catering_Links.Any()
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var q = from l in db.Locations
        select new LocationWrap 
        {
            Location = l,
            hasCatering = db.Location_Catering_Links.Any(x => x.ID==l.ID)
        };
```

So there isn't any need for a join.

Comment: you've got a typo in your answer. It should be `x=>x.ID==l.ID`.

Comment: @Serv oops. Thank you very much !